# Is dropping the clone of mpsc::channel::Sender explicitely necessary?

Tags: rust

I found the following code snippet on the internet.

```rust
fn send_efficiently<T: Copy>(
    sender: &mut Sender<T>,
    value: T,
) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> {
    match sender.try_send(value) {
        Ok(_) => {
            println!("try_send accepted");
            Either::Left(ok(()))
        }
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Backpressure - using a clone");
            Either::Right(
                sender
                    .clone()
                    .send(value)
                    .map(|_| ()) // drop clone after send
                    .map_err(|_| ()), // ignore channel error
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know if this particular line  `.map(|_| ()) // drop clone after send`  is needed. Wont the clone get dropped automatically when we exit the function?

Comment: A [mre] should include what the named types are, I assume it isn't `std::sync::mpsc::Sender`, and the `mpsc` crate doesn't have a module `channel`. Also what is `Either`? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: `Future` also looks weird, `std::futures::Future` doesn't have `Error` or `Item` associated types, only `Output`. The code returns `Either`, but return type is `impl Future<...>`.

Comment: The snippet looks like it came from [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/tokio-stream-sender-ownership-backpressure/29600) and uses `tokio` types. The thread is from 2019, maybe some of the APIs have changed since.

Comment: @user4815162342: [`Either<L, R>`](https://docs.rs/either/latest/either/enum.Either.html#impl-Future-for-Either%3CL,+R%3E) implements `Future` if both sides implement `Future` with the same item type. That is a known trick to be able to return different types of futures from a function that returns an opaque `impl Future`.

Comment: @rodrigo So `Either` does a poor man's enum_dispatch for `Future`? Nice, I didn't know that. In this code the added confusion is that it uses wrong associated types for `Future`, but that's explained by Aurel.

Comment: @user4815162342: Indeed, `Either` is a poor man's dispatch for a lot of traits, not only `Future`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the `Future` trait has an associated type `Output`, but in the olden days, as @AurelBílý commented above, it used to have two: `Item` and `Error`, because all futures where considered fallible.

Nowadays if you want a fallible future you write `Future<Output=Result<T,E>>`.

One side-effect of every future being fallible is that all async functions should return an `Ok` or `Err`, `()` cannot be returned.

Ignoring the `async/Future` and the `Either`, your issue with that code is equivalent to this one:

```
fn test<A, B>(x: Result<A, B>) -> Result<(), ()> {
    x
}
```

That will not compile, because the types do not match. You want to keep the *errorness* of `x` but discard `A` and `B`. The straightforward solution is to use a `match`:

```
fn test<A, B>(x: Result<A, B>) -> Result<(), ()> {
    match x {
        Ok(_) => Ok(()),
        Err(_) => Err(()),
    }
}
```

But the first branch is equivalent to calling `Result::map` and the second to `Result::map_err`, so you can do instead:

```
fn test<A, B>(x: Result<A, B>) -> Result<(), ()> {
    x
        .map(|_| => ())
        .map_err(|_| => ())
}
```

That is basically what you see.
Or if you prefer:

```
fn test<A, B>(x: Result<A, B>) -> Result<(), ()> {
    x
        .map(drop)
        .map_err(drop)
}
```

You are right that the drop would be done automatically. But it is not the drop itself what is needed here, but the change in type. This would work too without doing anything to `x`:

```
fn test<A, B>(x: Result<A, B>) -> Result<(), ()> {
    let is_ok = x.is_ok();
    if is_ok { Ok(()) } else { Err(()) }
    // x is dropped, all goes well
}
```

Comment: @user4815162342: You are right, that was sloppy wording from my part, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

At the time the snippet was posted, the APIs and traits looked a bit different (in [`futures` 0.1.27](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.27/futures/). In particular, [`futures::sink::Sink::Send`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.27/futures/sink/trait.Sink.html#method.send) has the signature:

```rust
fn send(self, item: Self::SinkItem) -> futures::sink::Send<Self>;
```

Note that this takes a `self` argument, i.e. the sink is moved into the method. To allow multiple items to be sent using the same sink, the resulting type [`futures::sink::Send`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.27/futures/sink/struct.Send.html), had a `Future` implementation like this:

```rust
impl<S: Sink> Future for Send<S> {
  type Item = S;
  // ...
}
```

That is, the returned `Future` would resolve with the original `Sink`. The snippet you posted then `map`s the future to a unit, which would indeed drop the "recovered" `Sink`. This way the return type also matches (it becomes a future with `Item = ()`).

The intent of the method was to avoid allocating a future if the `try_send` succeeds, and only allocate one if it does not and `send` is used. The `Either` then makes the types work (as @rodrigo points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77924852/is-dropping-the-clone-of-mpscchannelsender-explicitely-necessary#comment137380418_77924852)).

The current definition of [`send`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.30/futures/sink/trait.SinkExt.html#method.send) instead takes the sink as a mutable reference, then keeps the mutable borrow in the resulting [`Send`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.30/futures/sink/struct.Send.html) struct. The snippet could be adapted to this:

```rust
use std::future::Future;
use tokio::sync::mpsc::{Sender, error::SendError};
use either::Either;

fn send_efficiently<T: Copy>(
    sender: &mut Sender<T>,
    value: T,
) -> impl Future<Output = Result<(), SendError<T>>> + '_ {
    match sender.try_send(value) {
        Ok(_) => {
            println!("try_send accepted");
            Either::Left(std::future::ready(Ok(())))
        }
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Backpressure - using a clone");
            Either::Right(async move {
                sender.clone()
                    .send(value)
                    .await
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the current `Future` definition only has one associated type (as explained in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77926404/392025)), so now the error needs to be part of a `Result`. Instead of hiding it, it is propagated. But notably, there is no `map` to "drop" the `sender`: there is nothing to drop, only a mutable reference to it that is borrowed for the duration of the future returned from this function.